# Can I unlearn a skill to make room for a new skill in State of Decay 2?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

I have several books for learning a skill but all of my community members already have a skill, so they cannot learn from these books (as well as I have individuals with duplicate skills). Is there any way to unlearn a skill so I replace it from one of my books to further upgrade my base (gardening, computer electronics, etc)?

Or do I need to recruit someone without a skill to have them learn one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot unlearn a skill on a survivor.
You can't "override" a skill by just using another textbook and there aren't any facilities or conversation with the option to dispose of a skill.

Your only option will be to recruit a new survivor with an empty skill slot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I guess everyone I have recruited has already had a skill.